# Visualizing Trajectory with Moveit on RVIZ for ur10

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit, ros-melodic, universal-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I am using universal_robot and moveit packages to work on ur10 robot's rviz simulations. When I was following the tutorials for panda robot on moveit, i was able to move the robot to a desired pose by setting the position and orientation and visualizing the trajectory that it follows. I created my own node for the same purpose on ur10 and I I am able to plan the movement and see it on RVIZ, however I can't visualize the trajectory that it follows. I am not even sure if it's code related or activating some kind of check boxes on RVIZ.
Here is what my code for visualization part looks like

```
moveit_visual_tools::MoveItVisualTools visual_tools("base_link");
visual_tools.publishAxisLabeled(target_pose1, "pose1");
visual_tools.publishText(text_pose, "Pose Goal", rvt::WHITE, rvt::XLARGE);
visual_tools.publishTrajectoryLine(my_plan.trajectory_, joint_model_group);
```

I am using  ur10_moveit_config demo.launch file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321750/visualizing-trajectory-with-moveit-on-rviz-for-ur10/) by [rosberrypi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31252/rosberrypi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2019-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just solved the problem. On Rviz Display menu I was trying to show /rviz_visual_tools topic by InteractiveMarkers but it should have been the MarkerArray.

---

Originally posted by [rosberrypi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31252/rosberrypi/) with karma: 75 on 2019-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0